# Google API PHP DELETE request not working

Tags: php, api, google-api-php-client

I am using PHP and the Google_Client to send HTTP requests to add google users and groups and these are working.  I can't figure out how to get my delete requests to work.  I am getting a 400 error which I think means the syntax of my request is bad.  The PHP request is below...  I am trying to delete a member from a group.

```
$requestUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/*groupName*/members/*memberName*';

$requestMethod = 'DELETE';

$requestHeader = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Content-Length' => 'CONTENT_LENGTH');

$postBody ='';

$request = new Google_Http_Request($requestUrl , $requestMethod,  $requestHeader, $postBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

V1 is deprecated. Use the V2 now in the Developers page to fully check your request. Also to be able to delete any type of file, permission or user, you must have the permission as an owner or such.